# PHP timezone. Where is my city?

Tags: php

Aparently, PHP doesn't recognize the State of Utah because I can't find the timezone for that area. Can someone please tell me what to use?" My server is in Salt Lake City.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mountain Time   UTC-7   UTC-6   MST MDT America/Denver

Comment: Thanks jscal. I had no idea, I live in the Pacific area. :)

Answer (score 0):

[Mountain: UTC-7/-6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utah) according to Wikipedia.

But it sounds like you have a different problem. At what point is PHP not recognizing the location, and what error messages come up?

Comment: Hey Pekka, Have a look here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php. I can't find what you posted in there.

Comment: There are no errors. I'm just trying to set the timezone based on my servers area.

Comment: It should be America/Phoenix according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_Standard_Time_Zone

Comment: @Pekka: Except that Phoenix is in Arizona, which does not observe the same Daylight Saving Time rules as the rest of the Mountain Time Zone.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Wikipedia page on the Zoneinfo database (aka the Olson database)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoneinfo):

> Usually the most populous city in a region is chosen to represent the entire time zone, although other cities may be selected if they are more widely known or result in a less ambiguous name.

As [jspcal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960377/php-timezone-where-is-my-city/1960387#1960387) points out, the Zoneinfo name for Mountain Time is `America/Denver`.